# Как отфильтровать реально существующие COM порты в Linux?

Tags: linux, внешние-устройства

/dev/ttyS[0-31] прописаны в системе, но существуют физически только несколько

```
$ echo "" > /dev/ttyS0 
# успешно
$ echo "" > /dev/ttyS31
bash: echo: ошибка записи: Ошибка ввода/вывода
```

Как понять какие существуют?

Comment: Тебе скрипт нужен или код на си?

Comment: как бы это не звучало: да

Comment: Если скрипт, то для начала установи пакет `setserial`, потом вызови его `setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123]`

Comment: Мне вот что дало: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzRDN.png

Comment: мм `ioctl(3, TIOCGSERIAL,` ок, попробуем. но есть ещё усбшные порты - они без прерывания

Comment: @eri, можешь [`qtserialport`](https://github.com/qt/qtserialport) посмотреть: там или у удава спрашивают или в `/sys` копаются...

Comment: Я увидел только вызовы ioctl ну ещё вызов fcsetattr. Не более.

Comment: @Fat-Zer удав поинтересней был бы, но в два лень..